# How to connect to MongoDB EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

we have an EC2 MongoDB 2.4 instance from Amazon MarketPlace.
when i try to access it from my computer using the mongo command like so:

```
mongo xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

i get the following error

```
Error: couldn't connect to server xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed
```

- i can connect to the remote instance using ssh so it is reachable.
- the port is the default port 27017.
- mongod is running and working on the remote instance.

any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Port 27017 is not open for remote connections? Check your firewall

Comment: [Try this resource](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-remote-access-for-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04#:~:text=To%20allow%20remote%20connections%2C%20you,MongoDB%20server%20from%20remote%20machines.) I got resolved my issues using this.

Answer (score 23):

As frisky said, you have to open the port 27017 at the EC2 Security Group Console. 
(To know more about how to do that: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

But you also need to change the `bind_ip` variable at the /etc/mongodb.conf file. You need to comment the line or assign the ip that will be able to connect the DB to it.

Comment: saved my day! This tip for bindIp (which is locked to localhost by default) was crucial

Comment: mongodb.conf  tip worked for me like charm. Saved my time and nerves.

Comment: also .. dont forget to restart your mongod instance for the /etc/mongod.conf to take effect

Comment: We can change bindIp to 0.0.0.0 for connecting from all hosts. Be careful in this because anyone can connect to your DB if they know your server's IP. This can be done only on the dev server. Please don't do this on production server.

Answer (score 13):

The following two steps enabled the remote connection for me:

- 1. Opening the inbound rould for my VPC at port 27017
     VPC -> Security -> Security Groups -> choose your instance's TCP roule -> click "Edit Rules" -> add a rule with Type: "Custom TCP Rule", Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 27017, Source: Custom 0.0.0.0/0 -> save
- 2. SSH into your instance -> sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf -> set bindIp: 0.0.0.0 -> save -> sudo service mongod restart

After that you will be able to connect into you remote mongo instance with mongo --host YOUR_INSTANCE_IP

Comment: Thanks man, while everyone was saying just comment the bindip (not worked for me) but after setting it to 0.0.0.0 it worked like a charm.

Comment: DONOT do this without enabling `security` or you will be opening up your databases to the internet.

Comment: Thanks, brother save my day

Answer (score 7):

Since mongod is running and working on the remote instance, you can access your MongoDB content via

mongo xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com or 
mongo machine_elastic_IP

Before that you need to open Inbound port for that machine.By-default port 27017 is closed for external world.

For more info refer : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah/getting-started-security-group.html

Comment: Hi, I did exactly same as you suggested. I changed the security group of an existing instance by adding an inboud rue as follows...Type, Protocol, Port Range, Source as Custom TCP Rule, TCP, 27017, 0.0.0.0/0. But still iam unable to access it from outside. Any suggestions.

Comment: frisky my mongo db instance does not have any public ip or elastic ip how to connect to that ?

Answer (score 5):

Amazon created mongo security group without 27017 open.
opening port 27017 to my pc fixed the issue.

Comment: DON'T do this on a production server!! There is a good reason that this port is not in the security group. Opening the port is a major security risk and there is absolutely no reason for it (not even in non-production mode). Use a ssh tunnel or the mongo client via ssh directly on the remote!

Comment: if it's locked on a IP (as in the answer) it's safe to use to config the db

Answer (score 3):

Try to access xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017 from browser, if it works then ssh into the instance.

- Stop the mongodb server
- Remove the file `/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`

start the mongodb server again, and check if typing `mongo` takes into a mongo shell or gives any error.

If the error is present, exit from the instance and again ssh to check for `$mongo`, if it opens a mongo shell. Try a reboot after this changes if the error still exists after the above changes.

The only concern here is, before accessing it from any application. Mongodb should work independently in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 controls access using security group, so make sure that box accessing mongo db host is in the `security group` allowed to access this box and `port` is enabled for the same security group.

Another problem can be `iptables`. Check `sudo service iptables status` on the mongodb box and see what are the rules there.

Make sure there you enable appropriate ports as per `security` requirement of the box.